Scalebar customization in MapServer
I'm a beginner when it comes to the MapServer environment and I've been wondering if I can change the unit label beside a scalebar to my custom text. I have the SCALEBAR object defined like this:
  SCALEBAR
    ALIGN center
    COLOR 0 0 0
    IMAGECOLOR '#FFFFFF00'
    INTERVALS 4

    LABEL
      COLOR 0 0 0
      SIZE LARGE
    END
    
    POSITION LL
    OFFSET 20 20
    OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
    STYLE 0
    SIZE 350 5
    UNITS KILOMETERS
    STATUS EMBED
  END

It's set to display the distance in kilometers and labels the units as "km" by default. Now, would it be possible to put the whole word "Kilometers" or that word in a different language there instead? I tried with the TEXT parameter inside the LABEL, but it doesn't have an effect, which I suspect is because that LABEL pertains to all the text that's part of the scalebar, including both the numbers and the unit name.
